# Yesod Persistent: SQLite table with id row only

Tags: sqlite, haskell, yesod, persistent

My model looks like the following:

```
TestGroup
TestPerson
    firstName Text
    lastName Text
    testGroupId TestGroupId
TestObject
    objectName Text
    testGroupId TestGroupId
```

In this case the only thing in the TestGroup table is testGroupId. Multiple TestPersons can be in one group (one to many), and one group can have multiple test objects (also one to many).

The following code compiles and run but produces an SQLite error:

```
postAddTestPersonR :: Handler Value
postAddTestPersonR = do
    newTestPerson <- parseJsonBody :: Handler (Result TestPerson)
    case newTestPerson of
      Success s -> runDB $ do
        newTestGroup <- insert $ TestGroup
        _ <- insert $ TestPerson (firstName s) (lastName s) newTestGroup
        return $ object ["message" .= "it worked"]
      Error e -> return $ object ["message" .= e]
```

The error:

```
"INSERT INTO \\\"test_group\\\"() VALUES()\": near \")\": syntax error)"
```

If I open the database and manually add it this way it works and I get a new ID number:

```
INSERT INTO test_group VALUES (null);
```

Should I just try to do this in Raw SQL or is there a way around this with persist. A simple solution is just to add a dummy maybe variable to TestGroup and do `insert $ TestGroup Nothing` but that is a bit hackish and I would like to know if there is a way around it.

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution right now other than using the dummy variable. Someone suggested I create an issue https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/222

Answer (score 0):

It was an internal issue with Yesod. It has been resolved: https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/222